# Publishing to IIS with WebDeploy from Visual Studio certificate error

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, webdeploy, iis-10, windows-server-2022

I'm attempting to move to a new server. The new server is Windows 2022 with IIS 10. I've added my domain, lets use example.com, and added a trusted ssl certificate to it. The site is reachable and only accepts secure connections. I pinged the domain and the ip matches the server.

This is the certificate information when you visit the webpage.

[image]

My publish settings are set to that domain for all applications that I'm publishing on this server:

```
https://example.com:8172/MsDeploy.axd
```

When I go to publish though, it's giving me a message about an invalid certificate.

[image]
[image]

It's not seeing the certificate that I have for for mydomain.com. Does WebDeploy use a different certificate when publishing? I thought it would use the domain that I'm connecting to domain.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The certificate comes from here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/remote-administration/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7#configure-connection-and-logging-settings-for-the-management-service

Comment: Did you try to install the certificate in the trusted root certification authorities store?

Answer (score -1):

I know you haven't been active for a while. I have been looking for an old friend who goes by the same name you do and I just stumbled upon your profile. If you are SS#3301 from The Ark, contact me on Discord at V.#9221 Just know that the messenger you sent me (Samsungsingson) disappeared suddenly without a warning even though he had previously told me you would soon be available.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).